# Any ideas to improve rendering performance of this custom view?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I've did some learnings about Canvas API recently, and have a sample project here: [CanvasSamples](https://github.com/teoking/CanvasSamples)

My question here is how to improve the CircleRender and CircleBarFftRenderer's performance in the spectrogram sample?

CircleRender's rendering codes:

```
    override fun onRender(canvas: Canvas, data: ByteArray, rect: Rect) {
        if (mCycleColor) {
            cycleColor()
        }

        val rwh = rect.width() / 2
        val rhh = rect.height() / 2

        mPoints?.let {
            for (i in 0 until data.size - 1) {
                points[0] = i.toFloat() / (data.size - 1)
                points[1] = (rhh + (data[i] + 128).toByte() * (rhh) / 128).toFloat()
                toPolar(points, rwh, rhh, 0)
                // x1
                it[i * 4] = points[2]
                // y1
                it[i * 4 + 1] = points[3]
                points[4] = (i + 1).toFloat() / (data.size - 1)
                points[5] = (rhh + (data[i + 1] + 128).toByte() * (rhh) / 128).toFloat()
                toPolar(points, rwh, rhh, 4)
                // x2
                it[i * 4 + 2] = points[6]
                // y2
                it[i * 4 + 3] = points[7]
            }
            canvas.drawLines(it, mPaint)

            // Controls the pulsing rate
            modulation += 0.04f
        }
    }

    private fun toPolar(cartesian: FloatArray, rwh: Int, rhh: Int, start: Int): FloatArray {
        val cX = rwh.toDouble()
        val cY = rhh.toDouble()
        val angle = cartesian[start] * 2 * Math.PI
        val radius =
            (rwh * (1 - aggressive) + aggressive * cartesian[start + 1] / 2) * (1.2 + sin(
                modulation.toDouble()
            )) / 2.2
        cartesian[start + 2] = (cX + radius * sin(angle)).toFloat()
        cartesian[start + 3] = (cY + radius * cos(angle)).toFloat()
        return cartesian
    }
```

I did two optimizations for `onRender` method (stats measured by Android Studio Profiler):

1. Avoid creating float array in draw call. This improves: *avg from 14.39ms to 12.12ms, max from 24.08ms to 18.85ms*.
2. Caching rect width and width for calculations. This improves: *avg from 12.12ms to 8.06ms，max from 18.85ms to 10.85ms (based on optimizing 1)*.

But the `onRender` is still slow after these optimizations:
[image: Spectrogram View hw-trace]

Any ideas to do further optimizing on `onRender` method?

Comment: Eliminate the null check of `mPoints` if it is always not null. Avoid using `data.size - 1` repeatedly by assigning it to new variable.

Comment: I just tried avoiding repeated `data.size - 1`, but seems not noticeable reducing in Profiler.